# How to customize an interface to one use on TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this code and I want to use the interface `ILink` on `Link` component, but I don't want to add `linkType` property always that I need to use the `Link` component. I want that the propriety `linkType` be `default` when I don't declare.

How can I do this?

My files:

index.ts

```
import { StyledLink, ILink } from './styled'

export default function Link(props: ILink) {
  const { href, children, linkType } = props

  return (
    <StyledLink href={href} linkType={!linkType ? 'default' : linkType}>
      {props.children ? (children) : (href)}
    </StyledLink>
  )
}
```

styled.ts:

````
export interface ILink {
  href: string
  linkType: 'default' | 'applications'
  children?: React.ReactNode
}

export const StyledLink = styled.a<ILink>`
 ...
`
```
````

Comment: please share all styled.tsx file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can achieve that in the following way:

Make the `linkType` property optional:

```
export interface ILink {
  href: string
  linkType?: 'default' | 'applications'
  children?: React.ReactNode
}
```

Then set `'default'` as default value for `linkType`:

```
  const { href, children, linkType = 'default' } = props
```